# Retrieving information about Vagrant-spawned hosts from within Vagrantfile execution process

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Is there any way to retrieve information about hosts spawned by a Vagrant process, while still within the Ruby process executing the Vagrantfile?

I'm using Vagrant in conjunction with the [vagrant-google plugin](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-google) to spin up a series of hosts within Google Cloud Engine.  GCE assigns each host an IP address, and I need to reference the full list of IP addresses (for all hosts) in configurations created by subsequent provisioning steps on each host.  I considered trying to scrape output from `ifconfig` as executed by the shell provisioner, but I cannot find a way to get the shell provisioner to return output or return values back to the Vagrantfile process.

Any suggestions are appreciated; if Vagrant is the wrong tool for what I'm describing, please advise if you can suggest a more appropriate one (or a plugin).

*(Cross-posted to the Vagrant Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/cL5DRZiO8zQ)*

Answer (score 0):

Alvaro Miranda Aguilera on the Vagrant Google group referred me to this plugin:

https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager

It updates the /etc/hosts file on all Vagrant-provisioned machines, as well as the local /etc/hosts if you specify `hostmanager.manage_host=true`.

While this solution doesn't solve the more general problem of retrieving generated meta-data from newly-provisioned hosts within the source Vagrant process, it does provide a solution for the immediate use case of configuring provisioned app servers to point to one another.  Instead of using the arbitrary IP addresses Google assigns them, I can set up the configuration to use the host names, and vagrant-hostmanager will ensure that the /etc/hosts files on each machine are configured such that those names are correctly resolved.